# why math.round(1.755,2) result is 1.75 not 1.76 but round(1.7555,3) is 1.756

Tags: python-3.x

i use python3, the code below:

```
import math
print(round(1.755,2))
print(round(1.7555,3))
print("%.2f" % 1.755)
print("%.3f" % 1.7555)
```

the result:

```
1.75
1.756
1.75
1.756
```

why, does `round(1.755,2) = 1.76` ??

Comment: In general if the last digit is five or greater, it rounds up. Python `round()` also tends to round away from zero (round up).

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation for [round](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round)

> Note The behavior of round() for floats can be surprising: for example, round(2.675, 2) gives 2.67 instead of the expected 2.68. This is not a bug: it’s a result of the fact that most decimal fractions can’t be represented exactly as a float. See Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations for more information.

This isn't a problem with Python, it's just a property of floating point numbers.  There is a certain degree of error in the mapping between floats and real numbers.  This causes some rounding cases to be unpredictable.